# How to E-file 1040NR(-EZ)?

Tags: united-states, taxes, electronic-filing

How do I file 1040NR(-EZ) online via services like taxact?
On IRS site it says that 1040NR supports online e-filing(no info about 1040NR-EZ though)

Comment: "On IRS site it says that 1040NR supports online e-filing" where?

Comment: @user102008 https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040nr.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TaxAct](https://www.taxact.com/support/22172/2016/form-1040nr-and-form-1040nr-ez-in-taxact) has these instructions for getting to that form through TaxAct:

> 1. From within your TaxAct return (Online or Desktop), click on the Basic Info tab. On smaller devices, click the menu icon in the upper left-hand corner, then select **Basic Info**
> 2. Click Continue until you reach the screen titled **Name, Social Security Number and Date of Birth**.
> 3. Click the link **Should you file a Form 1040NR - U.S. Nonresident Alien Income Tax Return?**
> 4. The program will proceed with the interview questions for you to enter or review the appropriate information.

Comment: Between 3 and 4, you will be asked to buy TaxAct Plus.

Comment: And you can't pay their fee with a credit card issued outside the US, which isn't helpful for a non resident

Answer (score 4):

Per [Iowa state university](https://www.isso.iastate.edu/resources/taxes/iowa-tax-return) (not available any more), the IRS has 2 providers available.

> New for 2016 is the option to e-file the Form 1040NR nonresident tax
>   return.   The Internal Revenue Service (IRS) has made available two
>   services that will assist qualified users to electronically file both
>   Form 1040NR and the corresponding State tax return(s) free of charge.
>   Both programs will be available after January 23, 2017. They are:
>
> 1. Onlinetaxes.com

(this is not available any more.)

> 2. TaxAct.com
>
> Note that the shorter and easier Form 1040NR-EZ is not yet available
>   for electronic filing.